# Use getServerSideProps in Dynamic Routes

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use `getServerSideProps` in my file `[username].js` (which uses dynamic routing). To use dynamic routing in next.js, you need to use the two functions `getStaticPaths()` and `getStaticProps({ params })`. However, you cannot use `getServerSideProps` with `getStaticProps`. This is a problem because I need to use `getServerSideProps({ req, res })` to access headers containing important user info (such as `req.headers['x-user-name']`), and without that data I cannot properly add functionality to my application. What can I do here?

Comment: You dont "need" to use getStaticPaths and getStaticProps for dynamic routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` in a dynamic route file.

You can just use `getServerSideProps` and use the `params` object to get the username inside of it.

Example usage:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ params, req }) {
    let pageUserInDb = await User.findOne({ username: params.username }).populate('userRoles');
    return {
        props: {
            pageUser: pageUserInDb
        }
    }
```